# LeetCode Minesweeper solution in Ruby

Tags: performance, ruby, minesweeper

This is my solution to [this LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minesweeper/tabs/description).

Essentially you want to get the next board state for a Minesweeper game. All test cases passed and the submission was accepted on leetcode. The submission on leetcode was I used a depth first search approach (hopefully it is implemented correctly).

I believe the run time for this is \$O(n)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of total squares, and each square is visited at most once, correct? The space complexity I believe is also \$O(n)\$, as I keep track of each visited square in the `revealed_squares` hash. Also, I wanted to note that the `update_board` method at the very end is the default method provided by LeetCode for use in the test cases.

```
class MineSweeper
      attr_accessor :board, :revealed_squares
      def initialize(board)
        @board = board
        @revealed_squares = {}
      end

  def click_pos(pos)
    @overall_count = 0
    return @board if @revealed_squares[pos]
    i = pos[0]
    j = pos[1]
    if @board[i][j] == 'M'
      @board[i][j] = 'X'
      return @board
    end

    self.dfs(pos)
  end

  def get_neighbors(square)
    i = square[0]
    j = square[1]
    top = i - 1 >= 0 ? i - 1 : nil
    bottom = i + 1 < @board.length ? i + 1 : nil
    left = j - 1 >= 0 ? j - 1 : nil
    right = j + 1 < @board[0].length ? j + 1 : nil

    possible_positions = [[top, left], [top, right], [bottom, left], [bottom, right], [top, j], [bottom, j], [i, left], [i,right] ]

    valid_positions = possible_positions.select{|pos| !@revealed_squares[pos] && (pos[0] && pos[1]) }

    valid_positions
  end

  def get_mine_count(pos)
    nbrs = get_neighbors(pos)
    count = 0
    nbrs.each do |sq|
      i = sq[0]
      j = sq[1]
      if @board[i][j] == 'M'
         count += 1 
      end
    end

    [count, nbrs]
  end

  def dfs(pos)
    i = pos[0]
    j = pos[1]
    @overall_count += 1
    count_and_nbrs = get_mine_count(pos)
    mine_count = count_and_nbrs[0]
    nbrs = count_and_nbrs[1]
    @revealed_squares[pos] = nbrs
    if mine_count > 0
       @board[i][j] = mine_count
       return @board
    else
       @board[i][j] = 'B'
       nbrs.each do |nbr|
          self.dfs(nbr) 
       end
    end

    return @board
  end
end


def update_board(board, click)
  m = MineSweeper.new(board)
  m.click_pos(click)
  m.board
end
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you're using `@overall_count` for anything